# How to add local folder as dependency for firebase functions in the package.json?

Tags: firebase, npm, dependencies, google-cloud-functions

I have a scenario where , I have to compile an npm package to `es2015` for using in `firebase` functions . So What I did was , I just downloaded the package from npm and compiled to `es2015` using `babel` and added the relative path to `package.json` .

Tried a lot , but nothing working.

I tried a lot of paths like

```
{
  ...
   "dependencies": {
   "[package name]":"/[edited package folder name]"
  }
}
```

It would be great if anyone could throw some light on this .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , I figured it out .

I packed the package using `npm pack`

Than added the package as

`"lib": "file:packages\\lib-3.1.1.tgz"`

Thanks